# Change text with GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I cant change the form straight from the source, but i need to change something when this loads during checkout on a webpage:

```
<form data-v-ab49818c="" action="" class="w-full md:w-auto"><div data-v-312d7461="" data-v-ab49818c="" class="yogo-input-field text-center"><div data-v-312d7461="" class="flex flex-col"><label data-v-312d7461="" for="input-field-159998664"> Rabatkode/gavekort <!----></label><div data-v-312d7461="" class="input-container"><!----><!----><!----><input data-v-312d7461="" id="input-field-159998664" class="order-last" control-id="ControlID-3"><!----></div><!----></div></div><button data-v-ab49818c="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-full mb-6" control-id="ControlID-4"> Anvend rabatkode </button></form>
```

I need to change/remove "rabatkode" (discount code) from both label and button.

I think this will work for btn, where i want to change from "Anvend rabatkode" to "Brug gavekort":

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary w-full mb-6')){
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary w-full mb-6');
    for(var k = 0;k < elems.length;k++){
        var text = elems[k].innerText;
        if(text.indexOf('Anvend rabatkode') != -1){
            text.replace('Anvend rabatkode','Brug gavekort');
            elems[k].innerText = text;
        }
    }
}
```

But how on earth do i proceed with the label-element?

I havent been able to test this yet, as the GTM code has not yet been installed on the client.

Comment: That wouldn't work - you'd need to do `text = text.replace(...)` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can just try it out, you know?

Here's a snippet that has your target markup and a simplified way (using `querySelectorAll`) to target both of the elements and edit them.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".btn.btn-primary.w-full.mb-6")).forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.innerText.includes("Anvend rabatkode")) el.innerText = el.innerText.replace('Anvend rabatkode', 'Brug gavekort');
});
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".flex.flex-col>label")).forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.innerText.includes("Rabatkode/gavekort")) el.innerText = el.innerText.replace('Rabatkode/gavekort', 'Rabbit code');
});
```

```html
<form data-v-ab49818c="" action="" class="w-full md:w-auto">
  <div data-v-312d7461="" data-v-ab49818c="" class="yogo-input-field text-center">
    <div data-v-312d7461="" class="flex flex-col">
      <label data-v-312d7461="" for="input-field-159998664"> Rabatkode/gavekort <!----></label>
      <div data-v-312d7461="" class="input-container">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!----><input data-v-312d7461="" id="input-field-159998664" class="order-last" control-id="ControlID-3">
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
  </div>
  <button data-v-ab49818c="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-full mb-6" control-id="ControlID-4"> Anvend rabatkode </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Vauw - i didnt even know you could run code in here. Havent been using stackoverflow for decades. 
Thank you :)

Comment: GTM repsonds with: "Error at line 2, character 81: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function." ... Do you have any idea what that is about?

Comment: You'll probably need to switch to that mode or turn the arrow functions into regular `function (...)` functions.

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".btn.btn-primary.w-full.mb-6")).forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.innerText.includes("Anvend rabatkode")) el.innerText = el.innerText.replace('Anvend rabatkode', 'Brug gavekort');
});
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".flex.flex-col>label")).forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.innerText.includes("Rabatkode/gavekort")) el.innerText = el.innerText.replace('Rabatkode/gavekort', 'Rabbit code');
});
`


?

Comment: I de-arrowed the example in my answer, but yeah, that looks about right.